# Count the number of overlapping elements in Postgres array

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I have an array of integer as a column.

Is there a way to query the number of overlapping integers?

For example for the following 3 records:

```
COLUMN1
{1,3,7}
{3,4,5}
{1,2}
```

How can I get the number of overlapping elements with ARRAY[3,4,8] ?

The result for my example should be:

```
1 (element 3)
2 (element 3 and 4)
0 (none)
```

I've found

```
SELECT COLUMN1 && ARRAY[44,45,46] FROM table1
```

But that returns a true or false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you [install](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createextension.html) the [intarray](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/intarray.html) extension you can use the "intersection" operator from that extension:

```
select column1, column1 & ARRAY[3,4,8] as elements
from table1
```

returns:

```
column1 | elements
--------+---------
{1,3,8} | {3,8}   
{3,4,5} | {3,4}   
{1,2}   | {}
```

To get the number of the elements in the resulting array, use `cardinality(column1 & ARRAY[3,4,8])`

Comment: 100% what I was looking for!  Thx.